# Logging objects with certain properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, logging

How can i log all objects with certain properties with the browsers' built-in development tools? For instace let's say i'd like to log any object with a width > 1000px, a specific css-property or javascript-manipulated items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get your problem this should work for you

```
var arr = [{width:1200},{width:1200},{width:900},{width:1200}]

arr.forEach(function(obj){
    if(obj.width > 1000)
        console.log(obj);
});
```

prints

```
{width:1200}
{width:1200}
{width:1200}
```